# Flutter - How to prevent BouncingScrollPhysys from bouncing when it reach the end of a CustomScrollView?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

BouncingScrollPhysics by default bounce at the start and end of a ScrollView but I would like to over ride that. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 57):

You can set `physics` on `CustomScrollView` to whatever fits your need this way :

```
new CustomScrollView(
  physics: new ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  ...
);
```

For example you can use `ClampingScrollPhysics`, which will stop at the end of the scroll with nothing else.

Comment: I have use it in my AnimatedList and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics())
```